# yii2 foreign key dropdown

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, foreign-keys, yii2

I am trying to display a dropdown with a category list in yii2 framework.

The tables in my database are setup with foreign key and used Model and Crud generator to generate the code.

I am trying to edit the code now to change the textfield into a dropdown with the values from the category table.

```
<?php $categoryArray = ArrayHelper::map(\app\models\Category::find()->orderBy('name')->all(), 'id', 'name') ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'category_id')->dropDownList($categoryArray, ['prompt' => '---- Select category ----'])->label('category') ?>
```

This comes back with the error "2.yii\base\ErrorHandler::handleFatalError()"

Most related post to my problem refer to version 1 of the framework but can't find a good example how to do this with version 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I overlooked the error on top saying 'Class ArrayHelper not Found' this has been resolved by adding the following line on top:

```
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper; 

 use backend\models\Model_name; 

 <?= $form->field($model, 'Field_id')->dropDownList(
            ArrayHelper::map(<Model_name>::find()->all(),'Field_id','Field_name'),
            ['prompt'=>'Select XYZ']
       )?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `->asArray()` to your find query:

```
$categoryArray = ArrayHelper::map(\app\models\Category::find()->orderBy('name')->asArray()->all(), 'id', 'name');
```

Comment: Add print_r($categoryArray) to see if categories are extracted ok. Also investigate full stack of the error, perhaps it'll give you an idea what exactly causes the error. Or post it here. For me the code looks ok, perhaps it's somewhere else.

Comment: This is definetely not the reason because `ArrayHelper` can work with both array of models and array of arrays. Please add `var_dump` of `$categoryArray` and full stack trace.

Comment: I am new to yii framework and suddenly notice I overlooked the real error on topr: Class 'ArrayHelper' not found

Comment: So the problem is solved now? You can add the answer by yourself in this case.

Comment: Yes, by adding use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper; it solved the problem.